# How to get index numbers of array in PHP using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to parse data from an TV Shows API, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the index numbers.

Example:

```
{
"data": {
    "0": {
        "1": {
            "param1": "value1", 
            "param2": "warning", 
        }
    }, 
    "1": {
        "1": {
            "param1": "value1", 
            "param2": "value2", 
        }, 
        "2": {
            "param1": "value1", 
            "param2": "warning", 
        }, 
        "3": {
            "param1": "value1", 
            "param2": "warning", 
        }, 
    }
}
}
```

The "params" and "values" I'm able to get just fine, but I can't 'echo' the index numbers.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
$string = file_get_contents(api);
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($json_a['data'] as $seasons) {
    foreach ($seasons as $episodes) {
            if ($episodes['param2']=="warning") {
            // echo index number of season
            // echo index number of episode

            }
    }
}
```

I believe I've read that using foreach I'm not able to get the index numbers? If so, what would be the solution?

I tried 'manually' incrementing variables for season number and episodes, but index numbers may vary. They may not be sequential and some start with index "1" instead of "0".

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer here that most helped you - seems to have been answered by several people.

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)` instead of just `foreach (array_expression as $value)`. The `$key` is what you're missing.

[PHP: foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, I was indeed missing the '$key' parameter in foreach. It's working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a counter, just add the key in your definition of the foreach

eg.

```
$test = array('foo' => 'bar');

foreach($test as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . "\n";
    echo $value;
}
```

Outputs

```
foo
bar
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($json_a['data'] as $index1 => $seasons) {}
```

and similarly:

```
foreach ($seasons as $index2 => $episodes) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt encode your json but,

used an array like:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      1 => 
        array
          'param1' => string 'value1' (length=6)
          'param2' => string 'warning' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      1 => 
        array
          'param1' => string 'value1' (length=6)
          'param2' => string 'warning' (length=7)
      2 => 
        array
          'param1' => string 'value1' (length=6)
          'param2' => string 'value2' (length=6)
```

and here is the code:

```
$a[0][1] = array("param1"=>"value1","param2"=>"warning");
$a[1][1] = array("param1"=>"value1","param2"=>"warning");
$a[1][2] = array("param1"=>"value1","param2"=>"value2");

foreach($a as $key=>$val)
{
    foreach($val as $skey => $sval)
    {
        if($sval['param2']=="warning")
            echo $key."-".$skey."<br>";
    }
}
```